# Statically declared struct with method taking a non-static reference

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to use a struct (`Outer`), which is statically defined. `Outer` has a method that takes a reference to a struct (`Context`), where the lifetime of `Context` is shorter than `Outer`.

The following code can also be found at this [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5ebe27c40f707dc602c1d91894d8e5f):

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Doable {
    fn do_thing(&self) -> u8;
}

struct Stuff(u8);

struct Context<'a> {
    stuff: &'a mut Stuff,
}

impl<'a> Doable for Context<'a> {
    fn do_thing(&self) -> u8 {
        self.stuff.0 + 1
    }
}

struct Outer<'a, T> {
    buffer: &'a mut [u8],
    used: u8,
    phantom_context: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Outer<'a, T>
where T: Doable
{
    fn use_context(&'a mut self, context: &mut T) {
        self.used = context.do_thing();
    }
}

fn use_outer_with_context(context: &mut Context) {
    static mut buffer: [u8; 64] = [0u8; 64];
    static mut outer: Outer<'static, Context> = unsafe {
        Outer {
            buffer: &mut buffer,
            used: 0,
            phantom_context: PhantomData,
        }
    };

    unsafe {outer.use_context(context)};
}

fn main() {

    let mut s = Stuff(4);

    let context = Context {stuff: &mut s};

    use_outer_with_context(&mut context);

}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `context`
  --> src/lib.rs:45:31
   |
35 | fn use_outer_with_context(context: &mut Context) {
   |                                    ------------ help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `context`: `&mut Context<'static>`
...
45 |     unsafe {outer.use_context(context)};
   |                               ^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

I'm having difficulty understanding why the rust compiler expects/requires the lifetime of `context` to be the same lifetime (`'static`) as `outer`. Shouldn't it be ok for `outer` to outlive `context`, as it's only using `context` for the lifetime of the `use_context()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an elided lifetime here:

```
static mut outer: Outer<'static, Context> = unsafe {
                                 ^^^^^^^
```

Since this is a static variable, the compiler will infer the `'static` lifetime, hence the full type of `outer` is `Outer<'static, Context<'static>>`.

Consequently, in the call to `use_context`, the type of the `context` parameter is `&mut Context<'static>`. However, `use_outer_with_context` is passing in a `&mut Context<'a>` (the `'a` is elided in the source).

The issue here is that `T` needs to be specified in advance, whereas in fact, `T` might change from call to call, due to the lifetime in `Context<'a>`.

Your sample can be made to work by moving `T` from the struct to the `use_context` method.

```
struct Outer<'a> {
    buffer: &'a mut [u8],
    used: u8,
}

impl<'a> Outer<'a>
{
    fn use_context<T>(&mut self, context: &mut T)
    where
        T: Doable,
    {
        self.used = context.do_thing();
    }
}

fn use_outer_with_context(context: &mut Context) {
    static mut buffer: [u8; 64] = [0u8; 64];
    static mut outer: Outer<'static> = unsafe {
        Outer {
            buffer: &mut buffer,
            used: 0,
        }
    };

    unsafe {
        outer.use_context(context);
    }
}
```

*Note: I changed `&'a mut self` to `&mut self` on `Outer::use_context`; the `'a` is unnecessary and can lead to compiler errors.*

There might be a reason why you wouldn't want to move `T` to the individual method. In that case, then I don't know of a viable solution. If Rust had [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265), then it would be possible to represent `Context` with the lifetime parameter pending application. Unfortunately, generic associated types are not implemented as of Rust 1.41.0.

Comment: I see, after reading about [RFC 1598](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) (generic associated types) this makes sense.

My goal of using T at the struct level was to give the ability to bind a specific instance of Outer to a particular context type so that I could only use that instance of outer with that type of context, but that's not really necessary.